# Can't install nugget package I made because package is not found

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I created a nugget package that contains 5 dll that I want to use as dependencies for some projects. I created a package source to `C:\Users\fernane\Desktop\test` via Visual Studio so I can select and install my packages from that directory. The package named `test 1.4.0.nupkg`is in that folder.

The problem I have is that when I try to install said package (test), I get the following error :

`Package 'test 1.4.0' is not found in the following primary source(s): 'C:\Users\fernane\Desktop\test'. Please verify all your online package sources are available (OR) package id, version are specified correctly.`

I created the package using Nuget Package Explorer.

ID of the package :  test
Version : 1.4.0

My question is the following : Why do I get this error and how can I install my package?

Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: The solution to my problem was the package itself which wasn't done correctly from my part, which led to this error when trying to install it. I did the package again via Visual Studio, and now it works. Thanks for your answer though, I appreciate your help.

Comment: You are always welcome :). Since you resolved this issue by yourself, you can convert you comment as answer with some more info about what you did, this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread and find the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is the following : Why do I get this error and how can I install my package?

Make sure you've "**all**" source selected in **Package Manager Console** and then try update-package command:

[image]

Alternatively, you can install that package via Manage NuGet Package UI, Right click your project->Select Manage NuGet Package->change the Package Source to your local feed->find the pacage, install it:

[image]